# DST in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, timezone, dst

How can I check in JS file whether current Date is in DST or not?

In C# there is the below code available to check this. Can anyone suggest similar code in JS?

```
var timezone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone
var tzById = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezone.StandardName);
var localDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tzById);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the C# code you provided.  You have a bug.  `FindSystemTimeZoneById` expects a value from the `Id` property of a `TimeZoneInfo` object.  You are looking it up by the `StandardName` of a `TimeZone` object, which *might* work, but only for some time zones, and only on English language systems.  The `Id` is not localized, but the names are.  Really, you should never use `TimeZone`.  Just use `TimeZoneInfo`.  If you want the local `TimeZoneInfo`, then just use `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.

But really, you have just written an elaborate version of `DateTime.Now`.  Your code doesn't do anything other than that.  The equivalent JavaScript is simply `new Date()`.

So, you asked how to determine if the current date is in daylight saving time or not.  I will also assume you meant for the local time zone.  In C# it is simply `DateTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime`.  In JavaScript, it is a bit trickier.

There are a few different ways, but this one is pretty easy.  See [this site](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldst.htm) for detailed explanation.

```
Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
}

Date.prototype.dst = function() {
return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
}
```

Now you can check `new Date().dst` and get a simple true/false result.